# Angular Routes not giving me any output

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-route-segment

**Why my routes not working well ?**

I'm sure that my code is true but no thing happen when I trying to run it , why the routes not routing the files ??

this is my main file code

**routes.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="MyApp">
    <head>
        <title>Routes</title>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div >
            <!-- my views -->
            <div data-ng-view=""></div>
        </div>

        <a href="#/view1">view 1</a>
        <a href="#/view2">view 2</a>

        <!-- angular -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>

        <!-- routes -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>


        <!-- scope -->
        <script>
      var myApp = angular.module("MyApp",[]);

      // define my routes 
      myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/',
            {
                templateUrl: 'view1.html',
                controller: 'SimpleController'
            });
          $routeProvider.when('/view2',
            {
                templateUrl: 'view2.html',
                controller: 'SimpleController'
            });
          $routeProvider.otherwise ({redirectTo: '/'});
      });

      // define my controller
      myApp.controller("SimpleController", function($scope)
      {
                // my array 
                $scope.customers=[
                    {name:'astm',city:'Alex'},
                    {name:'tamer',city:'Usa'},
                    {name:'ahmed',city:'Cairo'}
                ];

          // add new persons to my array
          $scope.addPerson = function(){
            $scope.customers.push(
            {
                name: $scope.newPerson.name,
                city: $scope.newPerson.city
            });
          };

      });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

This is the first view file  **view1.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>View 1</h2>
    Name :
    <br>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="filter.name">
    <br>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" data-ng-repeat="person in customers | filter:filter.name | orderBy:'name' ">
            {{ person.name}} live in {{ person.city}}
        </li>   
    </ul>

    <br>

    <h2>Add new person</h2>

    Name :
    <br>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="newPerson.name">

    <br>
    City :
    <br>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="newPerson.city">

    <br>
    <button data-ng-click="addPerson()">Add person</button>

    <a href="#/view2">view 2</a>

</div>
```

This is the second view file  **view2.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>View 2</h2>
    City :
    <br>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="city">
    <br>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" data-ng-repeat="person in customers | filter:city | orderBy:'city' ">
            {{ person.name}} live in {{ person.city}}
        </li>   
    </ul>

    <a href="#/view1">view 1</a>

</div>
```

Comment: try one controller for one view

Comment: tried it also but still not working :)

Comment: Typo may be... Though please provide a plunker

Comment: No error in the code , I also copied a lot of codes form the internet to test it and also not working !!!!

Comment: what server you are running this on.. Do check the network log if any request it is making for views html.

Comment: the project link : http://plnkr.co/85ghMSjVp0wXdEkDwCzW

Comment: I'm using Mamp and when i running the code I get this issue in angular.main.js line 38 :

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=MyApp&p1=Error%3A%2…b%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2FAngularjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A40%3A503)

Answer (score 1):

You have not added dependency of ngRoute in your app ..

```
 var myApp = angular.module("MyApp",['ngRoute']);

      // define my routes 
      myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/',
            {
                templateUrl: 'view1.html',
                controller: 'SimpleController'
            });
          $routeProvider.when('/view2',
            {
                templateUrl: 'view2.html',
                controller: 'SimpleController'
            });
          $routeProvider.otherwise ({redirectTo: '/'});
      });

      // define my controller
      myApp.controller("SimpleController", function($scope)
      {
        // my array 
                $scope.customers=[
                    {name:'astm',city:'Alex'},
                    {name:'tamer',city:'Usa'},
                    {name:'ahmed',city:'Cairo'}
                ];

          // add new persons to my array
          $scope.addPerson = function(){
            $scope.customers.push(
            {
                name: $scope.newPerson.name,
                city: $scope.newPerson.city
            });
          };

      });
```

[here is the working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SF8DDtKBCYURCDrODyrc?p=preview)

Comment: Hello , I'm really added it in my code but forget to add it in the stackOverFlow and my code still not working :(
This is not the issue and I'm still wondered  why it not working ??!!

Comment: Thanks Guys , I fount it work now 
and this is the plunker : http://plnkr.co/85ghMSjVp0wXdEkDwCzW
I don't know why it was not working  and why it work now , maybe my lap was want to restart it  :(